# Load php_oauth.dll into local server

Tags: php, apache, oauth, xampp

I'm facing problem to load the php_oauth.dll extension for my xampp. I downloaded the php_oauth.dll and added extension=php_oauth.dll in php.ini , but when i restart my apache, it cannot start the server anymore.

I'm using window 7 ,64bits.
Initially, I download the file from 
http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

but i found that it was 32bits file , so I'm searching fo 64bit and found out
http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions

unfortunately,I still cannot load the oauth. Any solution to solve it? I look through many article, but it seems like dont have it, anyone can provide ,so that, others that using win 64bit  can follow

Thank you!

Comment: PHP does not have x64 bit version on window. Download the PHP from official site http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4

Comment: hmm? after download the php5.4 and then can use edy?? because from this http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ , it do provide 5.3 php_oauth only..it that compatible?

Comment: I am voting this question up to get some more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be like a path problem. Make sure the extension is store in the correct extension directory.

The settings of this can be found inside `php.ini` as something like

> extension_dir = C:\php\extensions

By default this is **`ext`** folder inside PHP installation.

Or, follow the instruction from [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php) while installing extensions, if you are not sure what you are doing.

Comment: @Nich, Do a `phpinfo()` and see if you extension has loaded or not.

Comment: yah, i did ,but once i put and restart my apache, it cannot start the server, so that I'm not able to check with it. So, i think it's not loaded and causing error somewhere else.

Comment: @Nich, Upload the portion you were define the extension on `php.ini`

Comment: extension=php_oauth.dll
extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll

Comment: i added the extension=php_oauth.dll above the extension=php_bz2.dll

Comment: What is your extension directory? Can you verify the file exists on that folder??

Comment: yup, it located at C:\xampp\php\ext ,the file name is php_oauth.dll which exactly the same with in the php.ini. I'm running on win7 64bit, it that related?

Comment: May be the file you downloaded is corrupted. Download again and try again.

Comment: erm, i did tried that, but it makes my apache server can't start after adding the extension. I tried download&replace 84bit and 64bit ,but it still unsuccessful. Got other way to do it?? I saw this http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.setup.php but it seems like nt for window. I saw some post, there is another option that is compile to PHP, but how it could be??